# Running GDAL command in python within Windows OS

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, gdal, os.system

I am using GDAL in windows to perform some geospatial calculation. It installed successfully and running smoothly in command prompt. Here is the content of the batch file which is working:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -tr 0.1 0.1 -te 89.60 22.80 94.25 25.80 ../Precipitation/IMERG/precip.imerg.20190117.tif ../Precipitation/IMERG/meghna.precip.imerg.20190117.tif
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid ../Precipitation/IMERG/meghna.precip.imerg.20190117.tif ../Precipitation/IMERG/meghna.precip.imerg.20190117.txt
```

The problem is when I am running the same batch file within python using subprocess. The above command is not performing and no output is being produced. Here is the python sample code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("Batchfile.bat")
```

I also tried os.system which is not working. Any suggestion regarding it will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you report the error?

Comment: Hi Colin Stark, here are my outputs:
D:\FFFEWS_Operational\Bin>gdalwarp -of GTiff -tr 0.1 0.1 -te 89.60 22.80 94.25 25.80 ../Precipitation/IMERG/precip.imerg.20190117.tif ../Precipitation/IMERG/meghna.precip.imerg.20190117.tif 

D:\FFFEWS_Operational\Bin>gdal_translate -of AAIGrid ../Precipitation/IMERG/meghna.precip.imerg.20190117.tif ../Precipitation/IMERG/meghna.precip.imerg.20190117.txt 
Out[15]: -1073741515

Comment: I'm no expert, but I've found: "-1073741502 means STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED".
See: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2016-August/074634.html